# Generate a Django form from an array

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am looking for a way to generate a Django form based on a Python data structure such as an Array or a List of an un-specfied size or contents.

For example if the array contained ['Name', 'Question 1', 'Question 2'] a Django form with fields 'Name' 'Question 1' 'Question 2' would be generated. 
If array contained ['Question 20'] a Django form with field 'Question 20' would be generated.

I have looked through Django form factory, but I have not found a generator that works off an Array rather than a Django model.

I am a beginner with Django and Python so am not sure of any way to approach this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List cannot provide enough details about forms fields. Store forms as `json`: https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms